# What's wrong with this idea to solve for $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I'm a tad confused about whether it makes sense to solve simultaneous equations, if they aren't linear.  Does it make sense to solve a system of nonlinear equations simultaneously?

For instance:
$$
\begin{cases}
5 + \cos x = 14.5 \\
2.5 + \sin x = 1
\end{cases}
$$

Can the above system be solved for $x$?

What I would do typically is to isolate $\cos$ and $\sin$, square both sides, and rewrite $\cos^2$ as $1-\sin^2$, and get something on the LHS such as $2\sin^2x = \dots$

Take positive square roots, then take $\arcsin$, to get a value for $x$.

There seems to be a flaw with this method, though.

Comment: The above have no solutions as the two users have explained  below, but if you allowed for a complex number $x$ then there are solutions to the equations

Comment: Okay it seems like everyone is focusing on the fact that the numbers you chose (randomly, I assume) make it so that there are no real solutions. But what you're really asking is whether your approach is correct. While your description of the method is short, it seems more or less correct, or at least it should get you forward in solving the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system has no solution:

$$5+\cos x=14.5\implies \cos x=9.5\;$$

and likewise the other one...but $\;-1\le\cos x,\,\sin x\le1\;$ ...

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$5+\cos x = 14.5 \implies \cos x=9.5$$

$$2.5+\sin x = 1 \implies \sin x=-1.5$$

which are both impossible since $$-1\le \cos x \le 1$$ $$-1\le \sin x \le 1$$

We could consider

$$5+\cosh x = 14.5 \implies \cosh x=9.5$$

$$2.5+\sinh x = 1 \implies \sinh x=-1.5$$

which neither has solution since

$$\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x=9.5^2-(-1.5)^2 \neq 1$$